# Mongodb fiilter by date and aggregate pipeline

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to filter data for last one month and aggregate based on category column.

```
    end_date = datetime.now()
    start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=30)
    filter_query = {
        'load_date': {
            '$gte': start_date,
            '$lte': end_date
        }
    }

    count = await collection.count_documents(filter_query)
    print(count) # gives correct count

    pipeline = [
        {'$match': {'load_date': filter_query}}, 
        {'$group': {'_id': '$category', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}}
    ]
    items = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
    category = await items.to_list(limit)

    return {"total_items": count, "items": category}
```

count after filtering gives proper result. group by  category works if I'm not passing the time filter `{'$match': {'load_date': filter_query}}` in pipeline . But when I add both in pipeline, I get only total_items. Category returns empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've accidentally double nested `'load_date'` twice in the latter filter:

```
> filter_query
{ load_date: { '$gte': 1, '$lte': 2 } }
> match
{ '$match': { load_date: { load_date: { '$gte': 1, '$lte': 2 } } } }
>
```

Therefore the solution is to change the definition of the `$match` from

```
        {'$match': {'load_date': filter_query}},
```

to

```
        {'$match': filter_query},
```

Comment: Thank you so much for figuring it out! As a newbie to Python- MongoDB world, I didn't notice this and wondered what I was doing wrong here!